# When is it appropriate to use a NumberPicker view in a touchscreen device app

Tags: mobile, input-fields, numbers

In what kind of scenario should I actually use a `NumberPicker` in my mobile phone app user interface? By `NumberPicker` I mean a view on which the user can swipe to change the number, and the numbers increase or decrease based on the direction of the swipe.

[image: Illustration of a NumberPicker]

I really want to make use of it, but there are other tempting options, for example in Android a simple `EditText` and the `Spinner` and dropdown-lists. Both seem more lightweight than the `NumberPicker` and the time taken to give the input seems pretty much equal in all options. Actually, the `NumberPicker` is the only one that might interfere with other swiping actions.

Some background: in my Android application I have a `TabLayout` with 5 tabs and each asks an input from the user. One of the tabs asks for several number inputs, such as temperature, depth, speed and weight, and I am confused whether it would be good practice to use the `NumberPicker` for all of these inputs or just some of them, or none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number pickers like the one you have shown are only really useful when there is a small set of numbers to choose from, and ideally you wont have to move to many to get the correct input. The only thing that pops in my mind is to use it for time, such as a timer or alarm.

[image]

*While this particualar example is done with a spinner (iOS Alarm) it could easily and still very usefully be replaced with a NumberPicker.*

Answer (score -2):

I really want to make use of it, but there are other tempting options, for example in Android a simple EditText and the Spinner. Both seem more lightweight than the NumberPicker and the time taken to give the input seems pretty much equal in all options. Actually, the NumberPicker is the only one that might interfere with other swiping actions. [track landline number](http://mobilenumbertrackr.com/Trace-Landline-Number.aspx)

Some background: in my Android application I have a TabLayout with 5 tabs and each asks an input from the user. One of the tabs asks for several number inputs, such as temperature, depth, speed and weight, and I am confused whether it would be good practice to use the NumberPicker for all of these inputs or just some of them, or none of them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to UX.SE.  How does this answer the OPs question? Could you give a solution rather than a new question? Thanks.